# GPIO control for OrangePi 5B using C++

Tags: gpio, orange-pi

I am using Orangepi 5B for my project. I would like to know how can I use c++ for accessing GPIO pins. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Image provided by orangepi

Thank You

Comment: Via `libgpiod` you can achieve that.